# Recommendation for image addition API/library (meme generator-like)

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, image, image-processing

Is there any jquery library or API out there for image addition, allowing tasks like merging several images on one another, wrtiting text on top of images, and saving the created output?
For example websites like meme generator or canv.as propose such function. Thanks

Comment: Are you sure the PHP tag is relevant to this question? By the websites that you used to exemplify what you want, I think that you are looking for something running at client side.

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, look into ImageMagick and the GD library.

[ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) is great, and easily allows for what you're looking for.

[The GD library](http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php) is also good, BUT, not as flexible, in my opinion.

Since you have PHP tagged in your response, you will, however, find more native integration with the GD library, as they've written a wrapper for it.  So that might be a good place to go to start with.  I've worked with both.  When I'm using PHP, I typically use the GD Library, when I'm doing something else, like an application that lives on the server, agnostic from the web server, I use ImageMagick.

Comment: He doesn't ask for a server side lib I think.

Comment: He's got PHP as a tag.. both of those libraries can be used in PHP.

Answer (score 0):

look for GD library [gd library](http://php.net/manual/en/book.image.php)
a very simple meme generator is launched by pincaption, this meme generator is created by gd library [pincaption.com](http://www.pincaption.com/memegenerator)
have a look